# Change in php.ini not reflecting PHP Memory_Limit Master Value

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, composer

I am trying to install a composer package for AWS S3 integration and came across the Composer Out of Memory issue.

Upon checking phpinfo() I could see the loaded php configuration file is /etc/php.ini and the Max Memory Limit allocated was 256M

But while checking the file memory_limit allocated was 128M. I tried to change it and then restarted the server. But whatever I do the Master value remains at 256M.

I am able to change the values locally using .htaccess but unfortunately it wont work with composer.

[Loaded Configuration File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgnvD.png)

[php.ini values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo2Ll.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can search for other instances of the PHP memory_limit setting using the find command.

For example:

```
find /etc -type f -exec grep -H 'memory_limit' {} \;
```

This will search all files (recursively) in /etc that mention memory_limit.

As a note: The composer site suggests values as high as 2gb. 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors